# Images not (always) showing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I recently developed http://transparency.dk, and Im having this weird issue in Firefox.

In my header (see Safari or Chrome) i have various social icons above the logo in the header, but they do not always load in correctly in Firefox, on both Mac and Windows.

If i refresh the site enough times, eventually they load, but this makes no sense to me?

The code is standard links with images. Im using Bootstrap 3.0 by the way. 
Anyone has a clue what might could be causing this?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="identity">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="social col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <a class="righty" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/TransparencyDK"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/social/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" /></a>
                <a class="righty" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Transparency-International-Danmark/46651234295?fref=ts"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/social/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" /></a>
                <a class="righty" target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/transparency-international"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/social/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" title="LinkedIn" /></a>
                <a class="righty" target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/TransparencyIntl"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/social/youtube.png" alt="Youtube" title="Youtube"/></a>
                <a class="righty" target="_blank" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/social/rss.png" alt="RSS" title="RSS" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <a class="righty logo" href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/transparency_logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Loaded first time for me - Firefox 33.1 on Mac

Comment: Loaded first time - Firefox 33.0.2 on Windows 7

Comment: Same here.. v32.0.3, v33.0.2 and v33.1

Comment: that is so weird, I get this on both Mac and Windows
http://i.imgur.com/nDimrdN.png?1

Answer (score 1):

I know, half a year too late...
But I've tested it. Firefox has a problem to show images that use specific file names, such as `youtube.*`, `facebook.*`, etc. The reason (for me) is the Add-on Adblock Plus. (With Firefox tools you can also see classes that should not exist, if you use such file names, e.g. `img class="zzzqejbemsxhesolqtlt"`).
Try other file names, like `you_tube.png`. That solves the problem.